# Simulators vanished from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I just reopened Xcode and now I only see 6s simulators. All the others have just disappeared. How do I add them back ?

EDIT :

Silly me ,I missed that the scheme and target somehow changed to Apple Watch and I didn't notice. Should I delete this question :P .

Comment: Chack Deploy Target in the Ganral Tab Set 7.0

Comment: Deployment target is still 7.1

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode, click on 'Xcode' in top left of the screen, select 'Preferences...', once a separate window opens up click on the 2nd last tab called 'Downloads'. Inside, check the installed components.

If you deleted any previously installed simulators, then you should be able to re-download them here.

Answer (score 1):

check whether simulators are installed or not by preferences section in xcode. Or it might just be glitch. Restart your computer and Xcode

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Xcode -> window -> devices

follow this steps

1) [image: Step 1]

2) select the devices options, you will be able to see this screen

[image: Step 2]

3) click on add button. and add the simulator you want like this

[image: Step 3]

Comment: The simulators I want are already listed there. But don't list as an option when I want to run.

Comment: please check your deployment targets